# How to use bash to run `mkdir -m -p`?

Tags: bash

I want to `mkdir` as:

```
site1/www,site1/log
site2/www,site2/log
site3/www,site3/log
```

And permission of these folders is `700`.

Then I tried script in Bash shell as below:

```
sites_arr=(site1 site2 site3)
        for sitename in ${sites_arr[@]}
        do
                mkdir $sitename
                mkdir –m 700 –p /var/${sitename}/{www/,log/}

        done
```

But `mkdir –m 700 –p ${sitename}/{www/,log/}` always give me error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘–m’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘700’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘–p’: File exists
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Does your mkdir support `-m` and `-p` parameters?

Comment: @IporSircer,yes

Comment: What's the result of `type mkdir`?

Comment: @borrible,`mkdir is hashed (/usr/bin/mkdir)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the wrong type of *dash* character. You typed an [en dash](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html) `–`

```
mkdir –m 700 –p /var/${sitename}/{www/,log/}
```

but options are specified with a [hyphen](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/hyphen.html) `-`.

```
mkdir -m 700 -p /var/${sitename}/{www/,log/}
```

This is probably the result of copy/paste magic with some word processors.

With the wrong type of dash, what you typed as options are interpreted as multiple arguments for `mkdir`, which then tries to create a directory named `–m`, one named `700` and one named `–p`. This of course fails the second time the command is executed since those directories were already created.

Comment: Very nice catch! Well spotted!

Comment: I see this regularly with instructions posted on internal wikis for support staff (hello Confluence!)

Comment: OMG! I copy this script from a websites.