# Linux: Find command lists everything

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

So this is a strange one. I am using Linux AMI

```
[root@test /]# cat /etc/*release
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03
```

When I do a find command as a normal user with or without sudo for example

```
sudo find . –type f –name "*.sh" –exec grep -n “*rds.amazonaws.com” {} +
```

It will list every file within the root directory. Yet when I sudo su into root the command seems to work?

Comment: You may want to add the command that worked, its output, the command that didn't work, and it's output.    Also try doing `find --version` and `which find` when in user mode and in sudo.    Finally, your output has `"` and `“`, and `-` and `–` characters -- be careful when cutting and pasting.

Comment: It seems you have a copy paste problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53168529) question. (ndash vs hyphen and double-quotes vs left-double quotation mark)

Answer (score 2):

In the question, you mixed up – and - as well as " and ”. Those are different characters. For me, that command give this error:

`` find: unknown predicate `-n' ``

find interprets `–type`, `–name` and `–exec` (and everything in between) as path/filenames and then stumbles across -n.

Please make sure, that you entered the command correctly (as to the hyphen/dash problem)

However, you said, depending of `sudo` vs `sudo su` the command works or not. So, I assume for now, that this is a copy-paste problem as suggested in a comment already. (Possibly, it could be a locale related effect as well - not sure about this.)

Check to be in the correct path.

`find . -exec pwd {} + | sort -u`

Should show the path, the find command is executing in (and error messages, due to bogus command line options - the pathes added by find - to `pwd`).

Also, that `grep` regex seems to be wrong: "*rds" is bogus, `*` means "the previous character any number of times", like `grep "Hel*o" . -r` searches for files, containg the world `Heo` or `Helo` or `Hello` or `Helllo` and so on. If you want to search for every file that contains the string `rds.amazonaws.com` regardless of what is before `rds` then you should just use the search term `"rds\.amazonaws\.com\>"`. `\.` because you search for a literal dot (and not any character, `"H.llo"` searches for `Hello` as well as `Hallo` (and other bogus words like `H5llo`), and the `\>` because `com` shall be the end of the word, so it doesn't match `comic`.

If none of this helps, improve your question by adding some results of listed files depending on what exactly you did do.

Oh, and welcome to Stackoverflow, Nabil Aziz.

Answer (score 0):

It's a puzzle why your command is not working, but this one should be ok:

```
find . -name "*.sh" -exec grep "rds.amazonaws.com" {} \;
```